# Vaadin Framework 7 with Spring boot using Flow

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a legacy Spring Vaadin 7 application what runs on Weblogic as a war.

Since just to redeploy takes like 10 minutes, I want to Use Spring boot with embedded Tomcat.

Following This example I can run the application.
https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/integrations/spring/tutorial-spring-basic

Now my problem is that my application uses `VerticalLayout` from `com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout`
and my VerticalLayout is from Vaadin 7.

```
    @Route
    public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    
        public MainView() {
            add(new Text("Welcome to MainView."));
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to use  the `com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout` with Vaadin 7 components? (Like an Adapter, a post construct setting, anything....)

I've only found some suggestions to use Spring boot 1.X...that would be fine with me but I've not found a repository what I could run easily and add my Vaadin 7 UI components.

Comment: You can make your V7 parts run in V10+ with https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/tools/mpr ; And for a spring starter, you might have to put your archaeologist hat on - e.g. one of mine is "hidden" in a branch: https://github.com/christoph-frick/springboot-groovy-vaadin-starter/tree/vaadin-7 - e.g. code-search for the old deps in `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` on GH